# What are legal items in the INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES property?

Tags: cmake

My expectations are, that the items in the target property `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` are other targets. However when I use on Linux for the official Threads package.

```
find_package(Threads)
get_property(libs TARGET Threads::Threads PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES)
```

libs ist set to `-lpthread`, which seems to be a linker flag, not a target.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That property is populated by the command `target_link_libraries()`, and its [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) lists what can be specified:

- A library target name
- A full path to a library file
- A plain library name
- **A link flag**
- Keywords `debug`, `optimized`, or `general`

Therefore, link flags are allowed here, even if discouraged by the CMake documentation.